# Visual Studio trying to use 64bit C runtime lib when compiling for 32bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

When I try to compile my program I get the following error:

```
Error   226 error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'   C:\dev\VAVTC\AMI-Intel\AVTC\2012_06_DemoCode\ElansMatting\msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll)
```

My target machine under Linker>Advanced is set to MachineX86 so I'm pretty lost.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. :P

For some reason under Project Properties>VC++ Directories Library Directories had been set to the Amd64 Libs instead of the 32bit ones